# Чем являются числительное и существительное

Tags: члены-предложения

а когда числительное с существительным вместе образуют подлежащее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Это части речи.
2. Когда подлежащее – цельное, то есть синтаксически неделимое словосочетание (главное + зависимое слово):

   `Пять стульев стояло у стены.`